# shows "Unexpected use of reserved word 'class' No stack" on emulator

Tags: react-native, android-studio

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRfC8.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X9W7.png

I'm trying to run a react native app on emulator but I'm getting this strange error. I can't get any details or where on my code this problem exist.

package.json

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEy2E.png

Comment: Could you please share your `package.json` file of your project?

Comment: I have added package.json file.